# How can i add the row dynamically at an exact postion in a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I write a code to add dynamical column and row to a data set but the field is added some where in my data-set so can any one tell how can I resolve this

My code

```
for (int i = 0; i < AchDB.Amount1.Count; i++)
    {
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Amount1");
        local_ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dc);
        local_ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(AchDB.Amount1[i]);
    }
```

I need as per in the image shown

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use this:

```
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Amount1");
local_ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dc);

for (int i = 0; i < AchDB.Amount1.Count; i++)
{
    local_ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Amount1"] = AchDB.Amount1[i];
}
```

I did put the code for adding a new column outside the loop. I think adding the column once will be applicable for all rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "InsertAt" method of DataTable for inserting the row at specific position. For the columns there is no direct way of adding a column at a specific position. When you add a column to a datatable - it always gets added at the last.

```
dt.Rows.InsertAt(newRowObject,pos);
```